# Does having a Unix socket file on an SSD yield any performance increase?

Tags: linux, sockets, file-io, filesystems, freebsd

As far as I have always understood, socket files (.sock) are simply data structures that provide the convenience of file handling instructions for memory structures.  Recently, however, I have been curious with the introduction of SSD drives for some servers as to whether or not there is any kind of actual IO being performed on disk upon these sockets or if it is truly entirely in memory.

So what is the true case here?  Would having socket files relocated to an SSD yield any performance increases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, there is no io done on underlying fs where the pipe is located.

And one can easily test that like

- mkfifo pipe0
- cat /dev/zero > pipe0
- pv pipe0 > /dev/null

And run `iotop` as root to see that there's no io on disk.